# Where in mysql i can change language to default (eng)?

Tags: magento-2.1, database, language, language-package

I change default language in user settings, and style CSS is broken.
Also i cant change it back - button "save" not work.

Where in mysql i can change language and how.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

clear your static content folder :

```
rm -rf pub/static/frontend pub/static/admninhtml var/view_processed/pub
```

and then redploy static content :

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

hope it will solve the issue.